# Getting proper sourcemaps (gulp sass + cleanCss + prefixer + uncss)

Tags: sass, gulp, source-maps, autoprefixer, uncss

What is best way to chain gulp for compiling sass into clean css (prefixed, un-CSSed and minified).

Following example creates sourcemaps, but they are pointing to wrong line numbers in source files when viewed in browser inspector.

```
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    bourbon = require('node-bourbon').includePaths,
    neat = require('node-neat').includePaths;
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(plugins.sass({includePaths: bourbon, includePaths: neat}))
  .on('error',plugins.util.log.bind(plugins.util, 'Sass Error'))
  .pipe(plugins.concat('styles.css'))
  .pipe(plugins.uncss({html: ['dist/**/*.html']}))
  .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer())
  .pipe(plugins.cleanCss())
  .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'));
 });
```

In an attempt to fix this problem I tried to output sourcemaps before `autoprefixer` and `cleanCss` but it results in an error related to "Neat" and "Burbon" paths: `Error: Broken @import declaration of "../neat" Broken @import declaration of "../colors" Broken @import declaration of "../variables" Broken @import declaration of "../grid" Broken @import declaration of "../tables"`

Comment: You say the "lines" are wrong. Does this mean the line numbers when you're using a browser's inspector?

Comment: Yes @henry, I am referring to line number in browser inspector. I'll update the question to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i work with this task, using CSSO instead of your cleanCSS but use whatever you want, the tricky part is the sourcemaps, sometimes mess up the paths.

1. Declare a source path
2. Init SourceMaps
3. Compile SCSS into CSS
4. Add the right prefix support
5. Paste SourceMaps in the CSS file generated pointing to the SCSS files
6. Compress the CSS file ( this probably remove the sourcemaps unless you told package to save comments )
7. Declare a dest path

**Gulpfile: SASS Task**

```
const gulp            = require('gulp'),

      autoprefixer    = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
      csso            = require('gulp-csso'),
      sass            = require('gulp-sass'),
      sourcemaps      = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


gulp.task('sass', ['sass'], () => {

  return gulp
    .src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({ browser: ['last 2 version', '> 5%'] }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While your answer is generally correct, this doesn't work in my case. Moving sourcMaps a step before css0 (or cleanCss) results in `Error: Broken @import declaration of "../neat" Broken @import declaration of "../colors" Broken @import declaration of "../variables" Broken @import declaration of "../grid" Broken @import declaration of "../tables"`

Comment: can you provide a git gist with your gulpfile code ? to test by myself

Comment: Sure, here is link to gist: [gulpfile.js](https://gist.github.com/raminv80/9c75e148c2d94653f3258ae56752aa20)

If you are intersted in the complete project, you can find it here at [https://github.com/raminv80/chug/tree/bower](https://github.com/raminv80/chug/tree/bower)

Comment: hi @ramin, can you fix your conditional in the _colors.scss file ? because is dropping me and error about not declare variables, an i think is not passing the $palette: chugdefault;   if ...  condition.

Ok the problem is about sourcemaps looking for "maps" in wrong directory, the console say is looking within node_modules/sourcemaps instead of node_modules/bourbon i have to go but tomorrow gonna try again ok ? sorry a little busy today